# Using memoization with imports, to avoid querying in database for variables that don't change very often

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In Django for an app I have the following structure:

```
app_name
 - const.py
 - models.py
 - forms.py
 - views.py
```

In `const.py` I keep the constants and I `import` them in the other 3 files.

I have some `variables` that I usually obtain from the database (using QuerySet) but this variables don't change very often(months).

I want to add this variables as constants in `const`, and only update this variables value, when they are changed (from `admin`).

I want to do this, instea of doing 1-3 querysets more every time in `models/forms/views` when are called.

If I add them in `const`, on every `import`of `const.py` the database querysets are executed, so in this case I just moved them form `views/models/forms` to `const`.

So I need a sort of memoization, that can be cross-files/modules.

I know how to do basic memoization, but it works only inside the module.

Answer (score 1):

First basic answer:

You can let - const.py at the project itself and import it easily

```
project_name
 app_name
 - models.py
 - forms.py
 - views.py
- const.py
```

More complex answer:

Add a model `Constant` and cache this table with an id at redis with the longest available ttl for caching

As I don't prefer anything to be file based for many reasons

1. Difference between them based on env.
2. Permissions for access for some level for developers.
3. No need to increase files which may be totally not in need.

for more info about caching with redis check this at [real python](https://realpython.com/caching-in-django-with-redis/)

Comment: I have separate/specific const for each app, I was looking for something using just python

Comment: add them at `__init__.py` file